# Win32 API Dialog is really laggy and doesn't work

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

This might be a silly question, so apologies in advance.

I'm still very new to Win32 API and C++ in general. I'm trying to make a simple program that interacts with the parent window and the dialog window, but whenever I run the program, it takes quite a long time to run, and when it does the dialog window is super laggy and doesn't work properly. If someone could help guide me to the right direction, that would be great.

**Video of the bug** 
https://files.catbox.moe/vgl6rt.mp4

**Dialog code**

```
LRESULT CALLBACK LoginDialogProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {

    switch (msg) {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wp) {
        case SUBMIT_BUTTON:
            char name[100];
            GetWindowTextA(USERNAME_INPUT, name, 100);
            SetWindowTextA(OUTPUT, name);
            break;
        }
    case WM_CREATE:
        LoginDialogControls(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
    }

}

void InitializeLoginDialog(HINSTANCE hInst) {
    
    WNDCLASSW dc = { 0 };
    
    dc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    dc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    dc.hInstance = hInst;
    dc.lpszClassName = L"LOGIN_WINDOW";
    dc.lpfnWndProc = LoginDialogProcedure;

    RegisterClassW(&dc);

}

void DisplayLoginDialog(HWND hWnd) {

    CreateWindowW(L"LOGIN_WINDOW", L"Login", WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 300, 400, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

}

void LoginDialogControls(HWND hWnd) {

    USERNAME_INPUT = CreateWindow(L"Edit", L"Username", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER, 10, 10, 200, 15, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    CreateWindow(L"Button", L"Submit", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 10, 50, 160, 38, hWnd, (HMENU)SUBMIT_BUTTON, NULL, NULL);

}
```

Comment: Dialogs are usually created with [CreateDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createdialogw) and use a Dialog Resource for their contents.

Comment: you forgot break for WM_COMMAND

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you Bursov. I feel so embarrassed.

Comment: Thank you Richard Critten for the advice. I will definitely do that!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/dlgbox-programming-considerations#dialog-box-procedures

Comment: You are returning random values from `LoginDialogProcedure`. Only `default` case has `return` statement.